# In Reporting API V4, different results using (or not) segment "All Users"

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the Reporting API V4 from Google Analytics in the "Try This API" Sandbox.

I use as dimensions `ga:yearMonth` and as metrics `ga:users`.

I have different results if I use the "All Users" segment in one case (adding a dimension `ga:segment` and a segment `gaid::-1`, this gives me wrong results), and if I request the API without the segment.

Users results in +20% if I use the segment, on the same view! The results in the Analytics UI with All Users are different and I can't see any sampling information.

If I add the Pageviews metric, pageviews match the UI values in both cases!

Any Idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the date range you're trying to query?

Comment: september 2018 to yesterday, but it should not be sampled